# How to hide Comparison of UUID lines in two ARXMLs with Beyond Compare tool

Tags: matlab, uuid, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3, beyondcompare4

When I am comparing two ARXMLs(can be considered as txt files) with beyond compare tool, then i can see two kind of differences:

1. UUID lines, which will change in every code generation from MATLAB.
2. logical/interface changes, which are modified/added newly.

but UUID lines are not so important for me. So I would like to know, How to hide the UUID lines Differences in the Beyond compare tool, while Comparing two files.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Can you add an example of the texts?  I think you could extend the xml-format by some special rules.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the ARXM, but I found an example in https://github.com/nikidimitrow/Learning-AUTOSAR-fundamental/blob/master/BasicsOfAUTOSAR/MyECU.ecuc.arxml

In BeyondCompare, you can go to `Tools->File Formats` and  take the xml-format definition for xml and use "Save as" to create a new format:
[image]

Then adapt the mask:
[image]

After this, you must define a new Grammar element:
[image]

Use the Text matching `UUID=".*"` and don't forget to mark the Regular expression flag.

After this you can compare with the new format. The UUID-difference is now an unimportant difference:
[image]

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer solved the problem, then please accept the answer (see https://stackoverflow.com/tour how to do it)